# Trying to create a vba pivot table and i get a mistype Match using different columns

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot table in a VBA script in Excel.

The code works and it is able to create a pivot table, but its strange that only work up to certain column. If I do any column from A to J, it will work fine, when I just try to use it and grab the range to column K, it doesn't work and I get the mismatch error.

Reading the documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839430.aspx
[enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839430.aspx)

I saw:

> Passing a **Range** object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly.

Is there another way to pass the range of cells that I want to use?

```
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable

On Error GoTo errTrap
    Set pvtCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Issues").Range("D1:J20"))
 'this one doesnt work
    'Set pvtCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Issues").Range("D1:K20"))

errTrap:
    Debug.Print err.description

Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=charts_sheet.Range("B2"))
```

The `K` column has strings same as the rest of the other columns, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i fixed like this

```
    Dim range_string As String
    range_string = "C1:N" + used_cells_count_string
    Dim the_range As Range
    Set the_range = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Issues").Range(range_string).CurrentRegion

    Dim objTable As PivotTable
    Set objTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=the_range, tabledestination:=charts_sheet.Range("B2"), TableName:="initial_pivot", HasAutoFormat:=True)
```

using the PivotTableWizard

and to refresh it i did

```
    Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
    Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Issues!$C$1:$M$" & used_cells_count_string)

    Dim my_pivot As PivotTable
    Set my_pivot = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").PivotTables("initial_pivot")
    my_pivot.ChangePivotCache pvtCache
    my_pivot.RefreshTable
```

i still believe there is a difference  trying to pass a range  than a string such sheetName!$C$1:$M$10